# Why did the 777-9 leave landing gear down during first flight?

Tags: boeing-777

In [Sam Chui's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TszIMD3549o) covering the first 777-9 flight, there's a shot of the plane over the clouds with landing gear still down.

[image: 777-9 over clouds with gear down - screenshot from Sam Chui's video]

I thought maybe the shot was from another flight. I couldn't find another video with exactly that shot, but [CNET's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4t7L6p2Rug) shows the landing gear remaining down for a long time after takeoff.

Assuming I'm correct, that the gear remained down for the whole flight: why?

Comment: I'm fairly confident Boeing does this for all first flights as a safety precaution, but I will let someone with more direct knowledge provide an official answer